# How do I create multiple accounts in an Azure VM?

Tags: azure, authentication, ssh, cloud, virtual-machine

How do I create multiple accounts on a VM? Ideally, I want different users to be able to ssh into my VM with their microsoft account and password.

Right now, I have my VM such that you can login in the following fashion

ssh admin_user@public-ip

admin_password

I would like for each user to be able to create their own credentials and be able to ssh into the VM using their own credentials (I don't want to share admin credentials with everyone). Is there a way to do this? My Azure VM is an Ubuntu Server LTS running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

The feature to use you AAD creds to log into an Azure VM is still in preview.  Below is a link on how to implement it if you want to try it out.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/login-using-aad

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSMvH.png)

[image]